# What is the best Java API to make a simple 2D building game?

Tags: java, 2d, building

I am trying to just experiment with Java, and I was wondering what the most simple API for Java would be to make a 2D building game (i.e. placing blocks, moving around, etc) for a beginner who only knows Java and not many other dependencies.

Comment: Take a look at the [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) as a starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://lwjgl.org/
This is an easy java api to use:)

Comment: probably because lwjgl is meant for 3d games (just guessing)

Comment: :/ Yes but it works for 2D as well.

Comment: iHawk, *why* is this an easy, or the best, Jave API to use for simple 2D games?

Comment: It is relatively lightweight compared to other api's, but is still very powerful. I personally have not used it to make 2d games though, I just thought it would be a good place for him to start!

Comment: Note this from the website: "LWJGL is not meant to make writing games particularly easy; it is primarily an enabling technology which allows developers to get at resources that are simply otherwise unavailable or poorly implemented on the existing Java platform."